# Spark Window close function, stage becomes null

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I have a Spark Window that I use as a popup window in front of my main application. I prefer this method to the PopUp Manager. However, I run into a strange error when calling the windows close() method. In the closing event handler, I have a function which does the following

```
public function closeHandler(event:Event):void {
    this.owner.removeChild(this);
}
```

The window's owner is WindowedSystemManager, but at some point during the removeChild phase, the stage becomes null, and Flex throws an error trying to close the nativeWindow because it cannot find a reference to it. Two things fix this,

1. Instead of calling window.close(), call window.nativeWindow.close();
2. Do not call this.owner.removeChild(this) in the closing handler.

I'm trying to understand what is going on, does anybody have any idea??

Comment: never have a child remove itself from it's parent, this is a recipe for disaster. Parents should always be the ones removing children.

Comment: What I've concluded is that in the window's inherited close() method, there is a call to `systemManager.removeChild(this)` that accomplishes the same thing I was trying to accomplish in the closing handler. The suggestion to call `this.owner.removeChild` came from [here](http://knowledge.robotlegs.org/discussions/robotlegs-2/3073-multiple-windows)